# PHPUnit: Ignore tests completely based on dataProvider parameters

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I want to test (functional) my Symfony controllers with PHPUnit 9.6 and in order to not have to have the same test cases in each test class, I had the idea to make an abstract class that contains the test functions and then has an abstract dataProvider function. This is my abstract class:

```
abstract public function getEndpointConfiguration(): array;

/**
 * @dataProvider getEndpointConfiguration
 * @testdox It grants access without authentication on endpoint $endpoint and method $method
 */
public function testItGrantsAccessWithoutAuthentication(string $method, string $endpoint, ?string $expectedUserClass): void
{
    if ($expectedUserClass !== null) {
        static::markTestSkipped();
    }

    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request($method, $endpoint);

    static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
}

/**
 * @dataProvider getEndpointConfiguration
 * @testdox It grants access with JWT token to $expectedUserClass on endpoint $endpoint and method $method
 */
public function testItGrantsAccessWithJwtToken(string $method, string $endpoint, ?string $expectedUserClass): void
{
    if ($expectedUserClass === null) {
        static::markTestSkipped();
    }

    $client = static::createJwtAuthenticatedClient(
        AppFixtures::getUsernameByUserClass($expectedUserClass),
        AppFixtures::getPasswordByUserClass($expectedUserClass)
    );

    $client->request($method, $endpoint);

    static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
}
```

To then have these two tests run for a controller, I create a test class for the controller that extends my abstract class, and there I define the abstract function:

```
public function getEndpointConfiguration(): array
{
    return [
        // No authentication required
        ['GET', '/api/info', null],
        // Authentication with User class required
        ['GET', '/api/me', User::class],
    ];
}
```

So my idea was to provide as third parameter a user class or null. If it is null the `testItGrantsAccessWithoutAuthentication` test should be executed for that endpoint and if it is a user class, the test `testItGrantsAccessWithJwtToken` should be executed. And as you can see I used the `static::markTestSkipped();` in both test functions depending on the provided third parameter.

The problem is that I don't like that the tests are marked as skipped in this cases. It would be perfect if those are completely ignored and don't even affect the final results of the test run.

One idea was to make two separate dataProviders and then pass in one the endpoints without authentication and in the other the endpoints with authentication. But then it can happen that a controller for example has no endpoint without authentication and then you would have to pass an empty array for this in the dataProvider and then there would be skipped tests in the final result again.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you need such generalized tests of a successful response (very often this gives false support). But if you're adamant about this approach, then what about this same general test:

```php
    /**
     * @dataProvider getEndpointConfiguration
     * @testdox It grants success response on endpoint $endpoint and method $method
     */
    public function testEndpoint(string $method, string $endpoint, ?string $expectedUserClass): void
    {
        $client = $this->getClient($expectedUserClass);
        $client->request($method, $endpoint);
    
        static::assertResponseIsSuccessful();
    }
    
    private function getClient(?string $expectedUserClass): void
    {
        if ($expectedUserClass === null) {
            return static::createClient();
        }
    
        return static::createJwtAuthenticatedClient(
            AppFixtures::getUsernameByUserClass($expectedUserClass),
            AppFixtures::getPasswordByUserClass($expectedUserClass)
        );
    }
```